# How to know what a program is doing?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to know what an executable file has done ( what files have copied, in what folder have copied this files, what key registry have edited, etc ) ?

Comment: Sysinternals tools, [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) in particular.

Comment: There's various tools from Sysinternals (now part of MS Technet) that can monitor pretty  much everything that's happening on a system. If you want something more granular, you'd want to attach a debugger to the app and then you can monitor it at the individual machine instruction level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I voted up the `procmon` answer. However, I'd like to add that `procmon` is pretty much just a tool to display and plot Windows' realtime registry key (`HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`) values. If you want to monitor some of that stuff programatically, you just have to write code to look at and process those same registry values out of `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA` yourself.

Answer (score 4):

[Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

There are different tools for the different operating systems for sure. For MS Windows the SysInternals package by Mark Russinovich and Bryce Cogswell has a lot of tools for this.

It has real-time FileMonitor, DiskMonitor, ProcessMonitor, Network monitor and Registry Monitor showing the information in very detailed and understandable way.

You should download the whole suite, as these are different programs inside it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062

Answer (score 1):

You can use utilites from sysinternals such as [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). With it you can monitor registry, file system, network access and something more(sorry, i can't remember all features.)